# Mathematica transformation rules with trig functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, coordinate-transformation, spherical-coordinate

I'm an occasional Mathematica user and I am trying to transform an expression from spherical to Cartesian coordinates.

My function is defined as:

```
g[theta_, phi_] := Cos[phi](Sin[theta])^2 Sin[phi]
```

I'm hoping to transform that function using the following rules:

```
Sin[theta]Sin[phi] -> x
Cos[theta]-> y
Sin[theta]Cos[phi]-> z
```

in order to get the result:

```
zx
```

Here is the code I'm using to do that:

```
g[theta, phi] //. {Sin[theta]Sin[phi] -> x, Cos[theta] -> y, Sin[theta] Cos[phi] -> z}
```

And the result I get is:

```
Cos[phi] Sin[phi] Sin[theta]^2
```

So no transformation occurred.

Is there a function or an option I could add to help Mathematica figure out that the transformation is possible?
Thanks!

Comment: First problem: `[Sin[theta]]^2` is a common syntax error. That should be `(Sin[theta])^2` or even just `Sin[theta]^2`. Next Mathematica does pretty simple exact pattern matching and doesn't have any idea from your patterns what you really want it to do, but that is a bigger issue.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the syntax correction, I'll fix it in the post - I'm very interested in any tips regarding that pattern matching issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will be sufficient

```
Assuming[Sin[theta]Sin[phi]==x&&Cos[theta]==y&&Sin[theta]Cos[phi]==z,
  Simplify[Cos[phi]Sin[theta]^2 Sin[phi]]]
```

which instantly returns

```
x z
```

That doesn't show you the steps or rules it used to arrive at that result, but because it considered x z to be "simpler" than your trig expression the evaluation process went in that direction.

There is a slightly more compact way of doing the same thing, if that matters. `Simplify` can accept a second argument which are the things which are assumed to be true during the process of simplification. Thus

```
Simplify[Cos[phi]Sin[theta]^2 Sin[phi],
  Sin[theta]Sin[phi]==x&&Cos[theta]==y&&Sin[theta]Cos[phi]==z]
```

will give you exactly the same result